# Oracle SQL Max with Joins

Tags: sql, oracle, max

I have 2 tables joined by a single column. And I need to use Max to get the latest date on one of the columns.

## Table 1 (tbl1)

```
id     name    join_id
```

## Table 2 (tbl2)

```
id     start_date    end_date
```

So far this is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tbl1.id, tbl1.name, tbl2.start_date, MAX(tbl2.end_date)
FROM tbl1
JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.join_id = tbl2.id
WHERE tbl1.id = 4
AND tbl1.name LIKE 'Something%'
GROUP BY tbl1.id, tbl1.name, tbl2.start_date
```

I don't know what's wrong. I get errors like

```
FROM keyword not found where expected
```

When clearly I have a FROM clause in my query.
Please help me guys.

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT prsl.PROJ_NO, NVL(prsl.DEADLINE, prsl.SUBMIT_DATE) AS prsl.COMP_DATE,
prsl.SPON_PROG, prsl.PROP_STATUS, prsl.AWD_START, prsl.AWD_END, prsl.AWD_AMT,
dlvr.DUEDATE, MAX(dlvr.ST_STAT_DATE)
FROM ra_v_q_ie_prsl03 prsl
JOIN ra_v_q_ie_pt_deliver dlvr ON prsl.PROJ_NO = dlvr.PROJ_NO
WHERE prsl.EMPL_NO = '{$empid}'
AND prsl.FIRST_PD = 1
AND (prsl.SPON_PROG LIKE 'UM-SSHRC RGP%'
OR prsl.SPON_PROG LIKE 'UM-SSHRC TGP%'
OR prsl.SPON_PROG LIKE 'URGP%'
OR prsl.SPON_PROG LIKE 'UCRP%'
OR prsl.SPON_PROG LIKE 'UIRP%'
OR prsl.SPON_PROG LIKE 'Creative Works%')
GROUP BY prsl.PROJ_NO, prsl.SPON_PROG, prsl.PROP_STATUS, prsl.AWD_START, prsl.AWD_END, prsl.AWD_AMT, dlvr.DUEDATE
```

Comment: are you sure this is the query you are running?

Comment: There's more to it but the structure is like that. I could copy and paste the exact query if you want me to.

Comment: yes..please paste the full query

Comment: seemed to work for me.......WITH tbl1 AS (SELECT   4 AS id, 4 AS join_id, 'Something' AS name FROM DUAL),
    tbl2
       AS (SELECT   4 AS id, SYSDATE AS start_date, SYSDATE AS end_date
             FROM   DUAL)
SELECT   DISTINCT tbl1.id,
                  tbl1.name,
                  tbl2.start_date,
                  MAX (tbl2.end_date)
  FROM      tbl1
         JOIN
            tbl2
         ON tbl1.join_id = tbl2.id;

WHERE   tbl1.id = 4 AND tbl1.name LIKE 'Something%'
GROUP BY   tbl1.id, tbl1.name, tbl2.start_date;

Comment: I've updated the original post. Please take a look.

Comment: Is it possible that {$empid } evaluates to something that breaks the query?

Comment: you are grouping for `dlvr.ST_STAT_DATE` and select `MAX(dlvr.ST_STAT_DATE)`?

Comment: @SashaPachev Probably not, I tried the query without the MAX and the GROUP BY and it works. The $empid is just a number with leading zeroes.

Comment: @DavidIsla Hmmmm, that was not intended to be like that. Let me try by removing the group for ST_STAT_DATE

Comment: @DavidIsla I tried removing it but the same error message is still there. Sorry I was trying a couple combinations to try and make it work and I just forgot to remove it there earlier.

Comment: Could you post an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) example?

Comment: think you need to change AS prsl.COMP_DATE to just AS COMP_DATE

Comment: @DavidIsla I don't know how to use that but let me give it a try. I might need a couple minutes.

Comment: @user2744722 When I removed the prsl. it now shows me a new error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put it in the comment but here it is formatted I think you need to change AS prsl.COMP_DATE to  AS COMP_DATE

```
SELECT   DISTINCT prsl.PROJ_NO,
                    NVL (prsl.DEADLINE, prsl.SUBMIT_DATE) AS COMP_DATE,
                    prsl.SPON_PROG,
                    prsl.PROP_STATUS,
                    prsl.AWD_START,
                    prsl.AWD_END,
                    prsl.AWD_AMT,
                    dlvr.DUEDATE,
                    MAX (dlvr.ST_STAT_DATE)
    FROM      ra_v_q_ie_prsl03 prsl
           JOIN
              ra_v_q_ie_pt_deliver dlvr
           ON prsl.PROJ_NO = dlvr.PROJ_NO
   WHERE   prsl.EMPL_NO = '{$empid}' AND prsl.FIRST_PD = 1
           AND (   prsl.SPON_PROG LIKE 'UM-SSHRC RGP%'
                OR prsl.SPON_PROG LIKE 'UM-SSHRC TGP%'
                OR prsl.SPON_PROG LIKE 'URGP%'
                OR prsl.SPON_PROG LIKE 'UCRP%'
                OR prsl.SPON_PROG LIKE 'UIRP%'
                OR prsl.SPON_PROG LIKE 'Creative Works%')
GROUP BY   prsl.PROJ_NO,
           prsl.SPON_PROG,
           prsl.PROP_STATUS,
           prsl.AWD_START,
           prsl.AWD_END,
           prsl.AWD_AMT,
           dlvr.DUEDATE,
           dlvr.ST_STAT_DATE
```

Comment: It now gives me this error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: `NVL(prsl.DEADLINE, prsl.SUBMIT_DATE)` also needs to be in the `group by` clause.

Comment: @Allan Thanks! I think it works now, I knew I had to put the NVL on the GROUP BY and that's why I put prsl. before it. I didn't know I had to type the entire thing at the GROUP BY clause again.

Comment: Is MAX not going to return a record with NULL as a value?